# how to call timer.start() in a function different from form load in c#

Tags: c#, forms, timer, load

this is my first time posting, but I was wondering how can i call a `timer.start()` function in a function that is different from `form load()`. I am using `openGl` in some graphic application and i want timer to execute according to farmer(newstatus) condition. Thank you in advance for your help. 
...

```
if (farmer(newstatus))
{
    timer1.Start();                           
}
```

Timer Event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if (sheepX < 0.7)
        sheepX = sheepX + 0.08f;
     if (boatX < 0.27)
        boatX += 0.04f;

      simpleOpenGlControl1.Invalidate();
}
```

Form Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: is the variable called `time1` or `timer1` ?

Comment: @colmde timer1.start() is the function I want to execute

Comment: @tugba, declare the Timer control as a global variable and you can call it any where you want.

Comment: _timer1.start()_ There is no such thing. Try `timer1.Start() ;` c# is case-sensitive!

Comment: @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala i tried to declare Timer timer1 as a gloval variable but an error occurred :..... private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1; the Type"Form1" already contains a definition for timer1.

Comment: oh! this means you have added the Timer control to the Form.  Didn't get actually where you are facing the problem.  If the timer control is added in the form, then you can access it any where in the code.

Comment: Is the `if (farmer(newstatus))` code in the same form as `Form1_Load?`

Comment: @colmde yes farmer(newstatus) and Form1_Load() are in the same form:<code> public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {.....} 

 public void Solve()
        {...if(farmer(newstatus))
{}
}
}<code>

Comment: timer1.Start(); //timer1 value is null

Answer (score 0):

The control which is added from Tool box to the form can by accessed any where in the code.  Here is an example to call the Timer control from other methods

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunMethod();           
        }

    private void RunMethod()
    {
        string newstatus = "accept";
        if (farmer(newstatus))
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private bool farmer(string value)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        if (value == "accept")
            isValid = true;
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: `bool farmer(int newstatus)
        {
            return ((status & 0x08) != 0);
        }` 
i tried the example you wrote but :An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in yazlab2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error occured

Comment: @tugba, can you put the code here.  May be you have forgotten to initialize object

Comment: Program.designer.cs delete timer description recovered .!! thanks